# margin-left : auto not working in IE6 and IE7

Tags: css

I have designed a page which has these CSS properties:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
```

It works fine in Firefox & IE 8, but it does not work in IE 6 & 7.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve? Can you show the surrounding HTML?

Comment: besides margin-left: auto, what do you have that is not working?  because just having a margin-left of auto doesn't mean a lot.  This is for a div?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set margin auto for both sides:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Hi Pekka, It is surrounded by table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the element that these rules apply, you need to use `margin-right:auto` as well, or in shorthand  `margin:0 auto;` which menas (*top/bottom 0 and left/right auto*).

But make sure the parent of the element is a block element and has a width larger it.